# Breakpoints on ARM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gdb, arm, breakpoints

I recently read that software breakpoints for Linux on ARM are implemented using `UND` instruction in ARM mode and the `BKPT` instruction in Thumb mode. Why are there 2 separate instructions used to raise software interrupts?

Comment: arm and thumb are two different instruction sets.

Comment: @dwelch I understand they are two different instruction sets. However, why is there a need to have 2 separate breakpoint instructions? ARM does not define what the breakpoint instruction is, Linux does(as opposed to how you have it for x86/x64).

Comment: Doesn't ARM have a `bkpt` instruction [starting armv5](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/CIHBIGGI.html)? Edit: never mind, if it's Linux, it probably needs to support all ARM versions.

Comment: Also there needs to be two separate breakpoint instructions probably because they're two different instruction sets (i.e. one breakpoint instruction for each instruction set). The fact that other instructions just *happen* to have the same name between instruction sets is probably just for convenience I believe.

Comment: if you are asking about the mnemonic for the human, that is all at the whim of the assembler (The program that reads the ascii and makes machine code) which varies from one assembler to another,  just like push was a thumb only instruction and arm didnt have one but then the assemblers started tolerating the mnemonic push for arm instructions.  anyway if it is about the ascii/mnemonic commands then that is simply a matter of opinion of the author(s) of the assembler, unless that person or those persons are here to share their whims, not sure you will get an answer.